# Indexed sets Prove $(\bigcap_iA_i)^c=\bigcup_i A_i^c $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here i my approach. I stuggle to get the curly brackets in.

**Attempt**:

$\bigcup_i A_i^c=({x: \exists i \in I, x \in A_i})^c $

$={x: \exists i \in I, x \not \in A_i}$

How can I proceed here? I dont see any impending connection with the intersection.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:I guess I am wirking backwards with the RHS to arrive at the LHS...

Comment: The string of formulas is: $x \in \bigcup A_i^c \text { iff } \exists i \in I (x \in A_i^c) \text { iff } \exists i \in I (x \notin A_i) \text { iff } x \notin \bigcap A_i \text { iff } x \in (\bigcap A_i)^c$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Is this called "element chasing"?

Comment: I dont know how you arrived at the last 2 "iff"'s

Comment: @shoggananna: The first "iff" holds because the statement "there is an $i\in I$ such that $x\not\in A_i$" is logically equivalent to "it is not the case that for all $i\in I$ we have $x\in A_i$". By the definition of the intersection operator, this in turn is equivalent to "it is not the case that $x\in\bigcap A_i$". The second "iff" follows from the definition of complements.

Comment: @shoggananna: Re "I don't see any impending connection with the intersection", why don't you think about this theorem in the special case $(A_1\cap A_2)^c=A_1\cup A_2$? You could draw a venn diagram! Hopefully this will give you some intuition about why intersections and unions are related.

Comment: @shoggananna: To draw curly brackets, put a ``\`` before the bracket. E.g. ``\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}`` produces $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: @Joe: do we need to prove in the opposite direction?

Comment: @shoggananna: I don't know what you mean by that. Could you please clarify? For the statement "$A$ iff $B$" to hold, we need $A$ to imply $B$, and $B$ to imply $A$.

Comment: @Joe: Isnt what MauroALLEGRANZA has done? Just from A to B?

Comment: @shoggananna: If you read Mauro's comment backwards, you will see that each "$\impliedby$" holds as well. For example, if $x$ is in the complement of $\bigcap A_i$, then $x$ is not in $\bigcap A_i$

Comment: @Joe: Thanks. Very efficient way to write the proof.

Answer (score 2):

Your first equality is not correct. The point $x$ is in $\bigcup_i A_i^c$ if there exists an index $i$ such that $x$ does not belong to $A_i$.

The set $\left(\bigcap_i A_i \right)^c$ is the set of points $x$ such that $x$ does not belong to $\bigcap_i A_i$. A point $x$ does not belong to all the sets $A_i$ if and only if there is at least a set $A_i$ which does not contain $x$.